# Erro Warning: include PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Voces sabem o que poderia ser a causa do erro?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu codigo de rotas:

```
<?php
class Rotas {
private $telaAtual = "primeira";

public function getTelaAtual() {
    return $this->telaAtual;
}
public function setTelaAtual($value) {
    return $this->telaAtual = $value;
}
public function verifyRoutes() {
if($this->getTelaAtual() == "primeira"){
    include "../backend/components/firstpage.php";
}

}
}
```

meu codigo da pagina "jogo.php":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Usando `../`, você esta tentando dar `include()` em uma pasta anterior a do jogo.php, para dar include em um arquivo a partir do diretório root do seu projeto você usa `./` ou caso você queria dar um include a partir do arquivo atual não precisa nem de `./` e nem de `../`, apenas o diretório.

Tente essas duas alternativas:

**1. Alternativa (a partir do root do projeto)**

```
include "./backend/components/firstpage.php";
```

**2. Alternativa (apenas o diretório do arquivo)**

```
include "backend/components/firstpage.php";
```